# How to change margin each of the characters of string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors, character

I have a string `"Hello World!"`.

I want to change each `margin` of the characters in the `"Hello World!"` word in JavaScript.
For example:

margin of "H" character is 5px;

margin of "e" character is 3px;

e.t.c

How can I do it?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: nothing. I don't know how to do it, so I asked question.

Comment: maybe a quick search on [google](https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#gs_rn=14&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=pNxB9Ldr-S9H7fhzc77nhA&pq=change%20color%20of%20first%20letter%20css&cp=26&gs_id=7d&xhr=t&q=change+color+of+individual+letter+css&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=change+color+of+individual+letter+css&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.dmg&fp=2cfbba3e6df87f53&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=643)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var message = "The quick brown fox.";
   var colors = new Array("#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff"); // red, green, blue
   for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++)
      document.write("<span style=\"color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";\">" + message[i] + "</span>");
</script>
```

And works great!

Comment: Same i have did in Javascript .. Good try

Answer (score 1):

```
var color = ['#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF'];

window.onload = function()
{
  var div = document.getElementById('sample');
  var str = 'ABC';
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
  {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      var text  = document.createTextNode(str[i]);
      span.style.color = color[i];
      span.appendChild(text);
      div.appendChild(span);
  }
}

<div id='sample'></div>
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4BPv/)

Have a look on the above code . It may help you . Reason why i used span here is i cannot style text nodes so the only way i can do is appending text nodes to a span

Here i have shown up only for three characters . You can do the same for 'n' number of characters

Answer (score 0):

The fontcolor method is what you need

```
<script>
var str = "Hello world!";
document.write(str.fontcolor("green"));
</script>
```

It is also worth noting that the arguments to fontcolor("") can also be a hex number, or an rgb form.
If you have any more questions just comment.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fontcolor.asp

Comment: this will format the entire string not individual characters as OP asked

Answer (score 0):

```
('.cls').each(function(){

 var str = $(this).text().split('');
 $(this).text('');

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        $(this).append('<span style="color:blue">' + str[i] + '</span>')
    }
    else{
        $(this).append('<span style="color:yellow">' + str[i] + '</span>')
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
str = "Hello world!";
arr = str.split('');
document.write(arr[0].fontcolor("yellow")+arr[1].fontcolor("red")
+arr[2].fontcolor("blue"));
```